# Numpy 'could not convert string to float'

Tags: python, numpy

I have a csv file with the values in the first column including variations of strings like '1m4.5f'.

When i try to use

```
data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=',')
```

I receive an error:

```
could not convert string to float: '"1m4.5f"'
```

I can't see the .5 being an issue?

Thanks,

Comment: As default `loadtxt` tries to create an array of floats.  That string can't be converted into a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.genfromtxt` with `dtype=None`

**Ex:**

```
np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',', dtype=None)
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)**

Comment: @JWoodley13 If an answer has helped you, please click the checkmark (below the voting buttons) to select it as the answer to your question.